# Meteor REST driver

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Is it possible for Meteor to use RESTful db driver instead of Mongodb?

I have started studying Meteor and I want to use it in a project I am working on. The problem is that this project uses MySQL. I want to keep using Mondb syntax for CRUD operations but instead of using the Mongodb database I want to use RESTful for a PHP web service.

For example, when I do: `Albums.find({'name': 'Atom heart mother'})` I want Meteor makes a GET request to `http://server/web_service.php/albums/?query={'name': 'Atom heart mother'}`

I don't care if Meteor is still using mondodb for the session, app state and some other stuff.

Thank you people, and sorry if my english sucks

Answer (score 2):

For the moment, Meteor can't be used with SQL directly - the best try at this so far is the [meteor-sql smart package](https://github.com/drorm/meteor-sql), but it's been inactive for a good while. And the [meteor roadmap](https://trello.com/b/hjBDflxp/meteor-roadmap) doesn't make SQL integration a priority.

The meteor iron-router does allow server-side routing, so you could potentially link your Mongo calls to server routes this way... but wiring this up to Meteor's real-time data might be tricky.

Comment: "doesn't make SQL integration a priority" - It's on there under consideration for 1.1. That doesn't mean it isn't a priority, they just said in the 1.0 announcement video that they want to lock down the Mongo API and finish implementing oplog before they work on other databases. In other words, they want to have a 100% ready Mongo-based solution before they work on other databases, but those other databases are still going to come.

Comment: Thanks Cuberto for the clarification - the last time I had looked at Trello it was under "Later", now I see it's been promoted to "under consideration for 1.1", which is good news !